# How to handle window object on nodejs for server-side rendering of reactjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, enquire.js, isomorphic-javascript

I am trying to implement server-side rendering for my reactjs application.
I am using webpack to build reactjs application, enhanced-resolve to handle importing of jsx files in nodejs.

My application depends on third party libraries like enquire.js.
When react application tries to import  enquire.js on nodejs, it fails with error
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Since window object is not available nodejs
how to handle libraries that use window for server side rendering  ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Webpack yet. However, I had similar issue using browserify and I solved it by creating two builds: one for browser one for node.js with list of modules to ignore. You could achieve the same effect by adding to webpack config:

```
{
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/file\.js$/)
    ]
}
```

Then you have to make sure that you are not making any calls to enquire.js by checking if `require()` returned false value or object with module functions.

Comment: can you share the workaround you did to solve this issue with browserify. Thank you

Comment: This causes an `e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));` error. Does not work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quite old question still if some one is looking at it.

Try

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.window = {};
}
```